# How to load drool file from in-memory?

Tags: drools, apache-storm

I have generated the alerts using the drools , i had created the drool files from database.Every time i am loading the `.drl` file from resource folder in the project because of this one i am doing lot of io operation.

I want overcome from this problem , any way is there to load drool file from `in-memory` same as cashing?

Comment: You can prepare a rule base by compiling and serializing the result. How are you creating your session now?

Comment: StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession(); like this i am creating the statefull session?

Answer (score 2):

That's Drools 5? Time to upgrade. But you just use the same steps as I've provided them using code for Drools 6; the class names have changed somewhat. You do this once:

```
  KieBase kieBase = ...;
  FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream( OUTPATH );
  ObjectOutputStream oos1 = new ObjectOutputStream( fos1 );
  oos1.writeObject( kieBase );
  oos1.close();
```

You do this for each run:

```
  FileInputStream fis9 = new FileInputStream( OUTPATH );
  ObjectInputStream ois9 = new ObjectInputStream( fis9 );
  KieBase kieBase1 = (KieBase)ois9.readObject();
  KieSession kieSession = kieBase1.newKieSession();
```